# Domain modeling using GORM in grails, how to represent an association

Tags: grails, associations, grails-orm, model-associations

I am learning grails and I came up with a use case. In my use case, a product has many users and each user can have many roles.

Here is my product class:

```
class Product {

    String name
    String description
    String vision
    Date startDate
    Date endDate

    static hasMany = [users : User, contributors : User, watchers : User, approvers : User]
    static belongsTo = User

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Here is my User class:

```
class User {

    static constraints = {
    }

    String fullName
    String email

    static hasMany = [roles : Roles, products : Product]
}
```

Here is the Roles Enum:

```
public enum Roles {
    PRODUCTOWNER ('ProductOwner'),
    APPROVER ('Approver'),
    CONTRIBUTOR ('Contributor'),
    WATCHER ('Watcher')
}
```

My question is specifically about the association between Product and User. I want to represent the fact that a product can have many users in different roles. Also, each user can be part of multiple products with a different role in each product. Is this the right way to represent this relationship? Also, I should be able to remove and add users to products and vice versa. What this also means is that, users can keep moving between roles and can move in and out of products. In this scenario, I probably don't want cascades to happen. How do I prevent automatic cascades from happening to CRUD operations for this relationship?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think rather than having roles and products in User.groovy, it will be better if you create a separate domain like UserProductRole. As you said user will have different role in different products then creating a separate domain makes more sense in business usecase and also doing queries

```
class UserProductRole{

    Role role

    static belongsTo = [user:User,product:Product]

    static constraints = {
        user (unique:['product','role']
    }
}
```

You can create composite key but I generally dont perfer it because it makes querying bit difficult.

And now you need to change hasMany in User and Product like following

[userProducts:UserProductRole] rather then having users or products

Comment: This is great. Let me give this a spin. For my needs I don't the unique constraint. I will play around with this and update here.